# Saving build definition is giving error in Visual Studio Team Service

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I have started build automation using vs team service. I have linked my github repositories with Visual Studio Team Services through personal access token.

Now I am able to select github repositories in Visual Studio Team Services. But while saving build definitions it is giving following error:

> Unable to configure a service on the selected GitHub repository. This is likely caused by not having the necessary permission to manage hooks for the selected repository.

Can anyone please help me how to resolve this error. Do we need to buy any service for build automation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's another situation that also provokes this issue, specifically related to configuring the *Continuous Integration* trigger.

I have a github account with my own repos, but I'm also a collaborator on a different project (which is a personnel not an organization repo).

GH allows me to create a personal access token and VSO considers it valid for use when configuring the *Repository* options on the build definition but it does not have the appropriate rights to create a *Continuous Integration* trigger acting as *collaborator* to the other private repo.

The reason is that triggering notification is performed using GitHub ***Web Hooks***. It appears that when first creating the CI trigger, VSO initiates a request into the GH API to subscribe to the `push` event for the requested repo ... except that the personal access token includes the `admin:repo_hook` right for your own repo(s), not any for which you are a *collaborator* as this right cannot be delegated for a personal account.

It took me a bit of experimentation to figure this out. 8-}

Within this context, I think there are two possible solutions:

1. Ask the repo owner to generate and provide you *his* personal access token with an appropriately narrow scope of rights;
2. Transfer ownership of the repo to an organization, be granted appropriate rights as a member of that organization, and then create your VSO endpoint using your GH user credentials instead of a PAT.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You can only build the github repositories hosted in VS Team Service **which you are authorized** to push to.

Two ways:

### Connect using your GitHub user account

1. On the Repository tab, next to the Connection drop-down, click the
           Manage link. The Services tab opens as a new tab in your browser.

   a.Click New Service Endpoint and choose GitHub.

   b.In the Add New GitHub Service Connection dialog box, select Grant authorization, and then click Authorize.

   c.In the new browser window, sign in to GitHub and follow the instructions to authorize Visual Studio Team Services to access your GitHub account.
2. On the Repository tab, select the Connection you created.
3. Select the Repository that contains the code you want to build.

### Connect using a personal access token

1. Sign in to GitHub and make sure you have permission to read the
   repository.
2. In GitHub, create an access token.

   a.Select the repo, user, and admin:repo_hook scopes.

   b.Copy the token to your clipboard.
3. Sign on to Team Services and create a build definition.
4. On the Repository tab, next to the Connection drop-down, click the
   Manage link. The Services tab opens as a new tab in your browser.

   a.Click New Service Endpoint and choose GitHub.

   b.In the Add New GitHub Service Connection dialog box, select Personal access token.

   c.Paste the token and give the connection a name.
5. On the Repository tab, select the Connection you created.
6. Select the Repository that contains the code you want to build.

More details you can refer the link from MSDN: [Specify the repository - GitHub](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/define/repository#GitHub)

Comment: The problem is that the account has to have Admin permissions to set the web hook. it does not seem intrinsicly imperative to have admin permissions to a  repo to do CI. CI is a thing that reads from the source repo. Perhaps it needs write permission to save some artifact but that wouldn't go into the source repo. This tool should be changed to allow manual setting of the web hook by an Admin and build with a normal account.